# How to authenticate Trello API user with read, write permissions using OAuth1Swift

Tags: ios, swift, trello

I am trying to authenticate a user getting `read, write` access permission to Trello API. I am using `OAuth1Swift` for authetication but cannot add paramaters to add a permission and `app name`.

How do we add these paramateers? This is my code below.

[OAuthSwift Library](https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift/tree/master)

[Trello API Docs](https://developers.trello.com/get-started/start-building#authenticate)

```
 func doOAuthTrello() {
    let oauthswift = OAuth1Swift(
        consumerKey:    "consumerKey",
        consumerSecret: "consumerSecret",
        requestTokenUrl:    "https://trello.com/1/OAuthGetRequestToken",
        authorizeUrl:       "https://trello.com/1/OAuthAuthorizeToken",
        accessTokenUrl:     "https://trello.com/1/OAuthGetAccessToken"
    )

    self.oauthswift = oauthswift
    oauthswift.authorizeURLHandler = getURLHandler()
    let _ = oauthswift.authorize(
        withCallbackURL: URL(string: "oauth-swift://oauth-callback/trello")!,
        success: { credential, response, parameters in
            self.showTokenAlert(name: serviceParameters["name"], credential: credential)
            self.testTrello(oauthswift)
        },
        failure: { error in
            print(error.localizedDescription, terminator: "")
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying everything, this is the solution:

```
lazy var paramaters:[String: String] = {
    return  [
        "consumerKey": "consumerKey",
        "consumerSecret": "consumerSecret",
        "requestTokenUrl": "https://trello.com/1/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope=read,write,account&expiration=never&name=AppName",
        "authorizeUrl": "https://trello.com/1/OAuthAuthorizeToken?scope=read,write,account&expiration=never&name=AppName",
        "accessTokenUrl": "https://trello.com/1/OAuthGetAccessToken?scope=read,write,account&expiration=never&name=AppName"
    ]
}()
```

The magic happens by adding `?scope=read,write,account&expiration=never&name=AppName` to the url parameters